# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys.Extended.UI' is null or not an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem on my page.  When it opens, it displays the following error message:

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys.Extended.UI' is null or not an object**

```
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="tsm" runat="server" CombineScripts="false" >

    </ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

and display error

```
$create(Sys.Extended.UI.ModalPopupBehavior, {"BackgroundCssClass":"modalBackground1","DropShadow":true,"PopupControlID":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_panelPopupAddDefaultAddress","PopupDragHandleControlID":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_panelPopupAddDefaultAddressDragHandle","dynamicServicePath":"/SJM.Framework.Website/Order/ActiveOrders.aspx","id":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_modalPopupAddDefaultAddress"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hiddenTargetControlForModalPopup"));
```

Can anyone tell me me what is the problem is.  I've tried, but I haven't found it.

Comment: Could you add more content from your `.aspx` file? What version of .NET framework are you using? What is the version of the `AjaxControlToolkit` library?

Comment: Version is Ajax Control Toolkit 3.5.40412.2 And .NET Version is 3.5 means 2008 version i am using

Comment: Aaaand this type of error is the reason I abandoned the MS AJAXControlToolkit entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a newer version of the `AjaxControlToolkit`? I am using (<strike>`4.5.7.123`</strike>) `3.5.7.123` and this problem doesn't exist.

Also, you might want to take a look at this solution:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1209962/2132128.aspx#2132128

Comment: Hi Alex i am in last of my project where i dont want to change new version of AJAx how can i fix in Ajax Control Toolkit 3.5

Comment: NB: There is also a compatibility issue with IE11 which causes this symptom.  http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27602/

Answer (score 5):

I got this error because somewhere I was using ScriptManager instead of ToolkitScriptManager. The moment i replaced Script Manager with Took kit script Manager application started working fine.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Excellent. Solved my problem, just one edit.. Replace `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">`

with `<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">`

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error when I was in a .NET 4.0 solution and the AjaxControlToolkit.dll file I was referencing was v4.5.x.y. The error went away when I tried an AjaxControlToolkit.dll file that was v4.1.v.w, where I don't recall what x, y, v, and w are.

To find out what version the AjaxControlToolkit.dll file is, right click on it after adding it as a Reference, and select Properties -- there is a Property called Version that will tell you.

Answer (score 1):

I have just resolved the "'Sys.Extended.UI' is null or not an object" problem by adding the directive:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

which was missing in .aspx code for some reason.

And by replacing `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />`

with

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ToolkitScriptManager" EnablePartialRendering="true"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by setting the `LoadScriptsBeforeUI` property to true like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smMain" runat="server" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true" ScriptMode="Release"></asp:ScriptManager>
```