# Creating Drop down with Check Box in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a dropdown with check-box using textbox and popup control extender but i am getting this error whenever i run it:

> Error: 'Sys.Extended.UI' is null or not an object'.

I am trying to make as simple as possible but not sure what am i missing here.  Here is the code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ddl_TextLog" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" BackColor="#FFFFCC" Style="background-color: #FFCC66" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>        
<asp:PopupControlExtender ID="TextBox1_PopupControlExtenderLog" runat="server"  Enabled="True" ExtenderControlID="" TargetControlID="ddl_TextLog" PopupControlID="pnl_Log" OffsetY="22"></asp:PopupControlExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="pnl_Log" runat="server" Height="180px" Width="250px" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" Direction="LeftToRight" ScrollBars="Auto" BackColor="#FFFFCC" Style="display: none">
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList_Log" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_Log" DataTextField="MDE" DataValueField="MDE" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList_Log_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:CheckBoxList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_Log" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DCR-DWH-MS-01-DA2 %>" SelectCommand=" SELECT DISTINCT MDE FROM myTable ORDER BY MDE ASC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Possible answers: http://forums.asp.net/t/1545091.aspx?Microsoft+JScript+runtime+error+Sys+Extended+UI+is+null+or+not+an+object
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562451/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-sys-extended-ui-is-null-or-not-an-object

Answer (score 0):

i had to use this and fixed my issue:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" />
```

Comment: my only issue now is when i make my selection from the check-box list, the panel stays open.  I would like the panel to go a way if i select another text-box so how can i do that?  please help.  thanks

Comment: Since you solved the original issue please mark this answer correct and then open another question.  Thanks